# Laravel 4: Blade template @foreach with different keys

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Right now, I have to create lots of blade templates because of the following problem.  I am seeking creative solutions for this issue.  One of them is to do a 'select as' query but Eloquent Model::with() does not support aliasing (as far as I can tell).

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->typeAs as $typeA) or @foreach($product->typeBs as $typeB)
        // same html for both typeA and typeB
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use an `@include` and pass a sub-view with a variable named the same for both cases:

```
@foreach($product->typeAs as $typeA)
    @include('view.name', array('type'=> $typeA))
@endforeach

@foreach($product->typeBs as $typeB)
    @include('view.name', array('type'=> $typeB))
@endforeach
```

You may refer to the [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) as well